# inflate goes thorugh collision object?

Tags: modeling

i got a lil problem i wanted to do this tutorial..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs&t=1158s
when i created the cage i must have made a mistake...
maybe i forgott to merge on center on a few points? i cant find the error no matter what i do when blowing up the inside, there is one spot in the cage where it goes through? can anybody tell me what i did wrong?

the cage is made out of mirror modifier... i also tried with applie dmodifier..
thx

[image]

Comment: Hello ! In the mirror modifier there is a checkbox called "merged" is it checked ? Also the normal of this face looks wrong here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP1ce.png According to the other backfacing polygons, this one should be see-through too. Try recalculating the normals with SHIFT + N

Comment: thx dude, u my hero :D this was the problem its working now :D